# Wordpress widget jquery datepicker disappears on widget save

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, wordpress

I am adding the jQuery datepicker on a wordpress widget and it works fine until I save the widget. After I save the widget the datepicker won't pop up again until I refresh the widgets page.

I don't get any console errors, inspecting the elements I see that `#ui-datepicker-div` is set to `display:none;` and won't change to `display: block;` nor the position of the datepicker after saving the widget.

Here's how I am adding the datepicker:

```
if( ! function_exists( 'jquery_date_picker' ) ){
  function jquery_date_picker() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
  }
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_date_picker' );

if( ! function_exists( 'call_date_picker' ) ){
  function call_date_picker () {
    ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
  }
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'call_date_picker');
```

Comment: The `admin_footer` is being printed **all over** the admin in every admin section, this may have unintended consequences... Check if [this solution](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117292/enabling-jquery-when-dragging-available-widget-to-sidebar-area/119176#119176) applies to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this, I'm not sure if it's the best, but it works for me. I moved the datepicker scripts to the widget class inside the function that generates the widget form. That way the datepicker is only initialized on the widgets page.

Then I call an onclick event to pop up the datepicker each time the field is clicked, and to prevent it from not showing the first time that the field is clicked I add the `datepicker('show')` method.

```
class Alert_Widget extends WP_Widget {

  public function form( $instance ) {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-datepicker' );
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        ( function($) {

            $('.datepicker').on('click', function() {
                $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" });
                $(this).datepicker('show');
            });

        })(jQuery);
        </script>
    <?php

  }

}
```